# Do i need to pass more than one model to the view or is there another way to do this?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my application i have 'Contacts' & 'Invitations' 
When i want to create new Invitation i want the user to select whom to invite from his contacts 'Using multiple check boxes for example. 
In the Invitation Controller , i want to pass an invitation model to the view as well as a list of contacts that the user has.

How can i do this in ASP.net MVC 3 any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you have a complex type Model? Something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Invitation Invitation { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view your model declaration is (assuming you're using razor):

```
@model MyModel
```

Comment: came here to suggest exactly the same :-) +1

Comment: @iyadalaqel yeah MyModel is a ViewModel as Raphael said :)

Answer (score 1):

2 choices :

- using a ViewModel (new class with references to all the classes you need)
- using a class as Model and a ViewBag for the second class

Comment: mmm i'm using the second choice as of now , but how can i loop over the list of second class in the ViewBag ?

Comment: if it's enumerable... foreach. If you don't want a foreach (but a for), you have to "recast" your ViewBag, which is dynamic : IList<Contacts> contacts = ViewBag.Contacts (and use contacts)

Comment: Why do always view bags come on when talking MVC, I've written an entire enterprise app without the need for them.

Comment: They exist... and so CAN be used. Of course they CAN be avoided. That's not because you don't need/like them that no one should use them, no ?

Comment: Well, I try to abstract MVC away from my Models to make it easier to test etc, if you can avoid them I think you should